# Which OWASP Top10 and SANS Top 25 for SonarQube 6.7 LTS?

Tags: sonarqube, owasp

I just downloaded SonarQube 6.7 LTS.  I know it'll detect OWASP Top 10 and SANS Top 25...but which versions of those lists?

For instance, does the built-in tag scan for OWASP Top 10 - 2013 or 2017 or 2010?

Does the built-in tag scan for SANS Top 25 - 2009 or 2010 or 2011?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find information about OWASP and SANS in the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Security-related+rules) page. The page contains links to the security version-pages used in the latest SonarQube version (6.7 LTS). Based on the links provided:

- CWE/SANS TOP 25: Version 3.0 Updated June 27, 2011
- OWASP: 2013-Top 10

See also this:

> To find rules that relate to any of these standards, you can search
>   rules either by tag or by text. The standards that a rule relates to
>   will be listed in the See section at the bottom of the rule
>   description.

So it is not the case that all rules can already be detected/analyzed.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, that link does not say which *version* of the SANS Top 25 or the OWASP Top 10 -- nor do the rules.  There are key differences between the *versions* of the SANS Top 25 and the OWASP Top 10. Example: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/owasp-2017-top-10-vs-2013-top-10/#gref